# how to get Qt Mouse Position all the time

Tags: c++, qt

So I have been struggling with this question for quite some time. I have tried many things, none of them seem to work.
So, I want to make a game in Qt, and one of the things I need is that player(QRectItem for now) rotate always to the mouse position. I just need to get readings of that position all the time, so not when i click or when I drag, all the time.
How can I do that?
I set

```
    this->setMouseTracking(true);
```

on a class that inherits for QGraphicsView class, also I have set focus on it.
Dont know if the problem is with overriding functions(dont know which one to override) or with focus.

```
void Game::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << QCursor::pos();
}
```

Did this but it does not work at all.
Btw, I am noob it Qt, this is my first project.
Thanks in advance! :)

P.S.
I have really done research, but if I have somehow missed topic with same or similar question that can solve this problem, just paste it and accept my apologies. :)

EDITED

Comment: Install an event filter. Or just override the mouse event handlers that qt provides.

Comment: Expecting us to go elsewhere to see what you're asking is unreasonable. Please read [How to Create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [ask].

Comment: Please add a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: I didn't say Google it. Read the links I posted, which clearly say that the **relevant portions of your code** must be **here, in the question itself**, not off-site at an external location. When people point you to information in the [help] pages, it's because **you  should read them**.

Comment: @KenWhite I misunderstood your comment, thats why i removed comment
i edited post a little bit, but i posted pastebin because i dont really know what is relevant and what is not. When you are new to something problem can be somewhere where you least expect it, and i didnt think its smart to post a whole code.

Comment: @JesperJuhl
Which ones do i need to override?
I think that is main problem :/

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation? I could tell you, but I'm not going to; read the docs.

Comment: @JesperJuhl
Read it, but i didn't get it which ones I need(they are kinda complicated for a new guy).
mostly that is what i'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can install an event filter on your `QApplication` object, examine the received events for mouse movement events, convert the resulting position into your scene, and then use it to orient your rectangle.

Look at `QObject::installEventFilter`. Event filters are pretty easy to use. When a mouse event is received by an object, its coordinates are in that object's coordinate space, so you'll need to convert from that to your graphics scene coordinates. There will probably be several conversions to get that because you'll need to map the received position to your `QGraphicsView` using mapTo and then map the result of that to your scene using `QGraphicsView::mapToScene`.

This should get you pretty close. Let me know if you need more help.